# Issues with "nohup" on Linux instance on EC2 Amazon Web Services

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, aws, nohup

I am working on the Ubuntu system on Amazon Web Services EC2. I have created an instance and need to run a node.js server on the system. Once I ssh into my working directory and use the following command,

```
:~/Test1$ node server.js
```

the server works fine. The code runs without any issues

Now, what I want is to run the server.js code even when the terminal is closed, as a background process. For that, I am using `nohup` command with `&`

```
:~/Test1$ nohup node server.js &
```

This, also gets the server.js started but the `nohup` command seems nonfunctional since the server.js stops working when I close the terminal. I tried the code with `sudo` command as well

```
:~/Test1$ nohup sudo node server.js &
```

but it does nothing.

What am I doing wrong? And, how shall I get this working? Thanks.

Comment: you can try to just [use systemd](https://certsimple.com/blog/deploy-node-on-linux)

Comment: @hhoke1 had at the link, will certainly try that out. Right now, I have setup a RDP connection to the server and am useing that

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same issue.
I was running my node server as you do:

```
nohup node server.js &
```

In this way, the process is running in the terminal session, that's the reason the process lives longer as the terminal session stay opened.

Instead, try to run the process in a separated session:

```
setsid nohup node serve.js &
```

Try in this way, it worked for me.

Comment: For Amazon EC2 Linux Instance, I'm running SSH from Windows with remote command   `nohup myshell.sh > 2>&1 &` and AWS implements its own disconnect handler which somehow still kills the process. `This answer actually worked` to keep the process (which in my case starts a java server) alive, allowing me to "deploy" from remote.